# custom jsonconverter in nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Let's suppose that I have the following json

```
{ id: 1, name: "Eddy Vedder" }
```

that shall be deserialized in the following class:

```
public class GuitarIdol {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Because of the fact that `GuitarIdol` is just an implementation of an interface I have created a custom `JsonConverter` class to help the model binder with deserialization. I have then decorated my class `GuitarIdol` with the corresponding attribute

```
[JsonConverter( typeof( GuitarIdolConverter ) )]
public class GuitarIdol {
}
```

This works very well if the object to deserialize is included alone in the body of a web api request. Example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create( GuitarIdol idol )
```

The problem arise when I am trying to include this GuitarIdol object nested inside another class. Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public GuitarIdol Idol { get; set; }
}
```

and so I have a different action method in the api

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update( MyClass model )
```

In this case my custom JsonConverter is correctly called as expected but the Json.Net library does not pass me only the part of json for which I am trying to convert but the entire json instead. Example:

```
{ idol: { id: 1, name: "Eddy Vedder" }, notes: "great music" }
```

How can I better code my custom json converter to be resilient and be able to parse only the string portion which is interested in?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for your problem as a console app?  In particular, can you create a demo that shows that the *Json.Net library does not pass me only the part of json for which I am trying to convert but the entire json instead.*  This is quite surprising to me, I've never seen this before.